# VScode jupyer not loading ipython instance installed in a conda environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have noticed this both on Linux and MacOS. I have a conda environment for data science stuff, which I have installed ipython, ipykernel, jupyer, and a bunch of other data science dependencies. In VSCode, when I try to select a python interpreter, it shows just fine.

I have been able to run regular python files without issue. However, in Jupyter notebooks, when I try to select a kernel, it is only showing the system installed python interpreter (/usr/bin/python and such). Oddly, sometimes if I click the 'Select kernel' button early enough, it will temporarily show the conda environment as an option, but then in a second it will disappear. If I click the option fast enough, it also just resets to the system python and when I try again to select the kernel, it only shows the system options.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs in python 3.11.

1. Open the extension store and change the jupyter extension to pre-release version.

[image]

2. Use command `python -m pip install jupyter` in the terminal.
3. Use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and search the following option:

[image]